# Dynamic generated Custom Directive Not loaded correctly when using TemplateUrl

Tags: angularjs

Custom Directive that is using  **TemplateUrl** is not evaluating  correctly the angular expression  whenever I try to **load the directive dynamically (e.g.: using Jquery and $compile)** as below :

```
var  scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("test1")).scope();
var _html='<div>{{name}}-</div><mydirectivewithtemplateurl Generated Dynamically Using TemplateUrl >Not Succeed</mydirectivewithtemplateurl>';
$('#content').html($compile(_html)(scope));
```

But:

1- When I put directly the same directive (using TemplateUrl) into the page as below :

```
<mydirectivewithtemplateurl waytoload="Generated Stastically Using TemplateUrl ">Not Succeed</mydirectivewithtemplateurl>
```

It is working fine.

2- Also works fine when I use Template instead of TemplateUrl and loaded dynamically the same way as above:

```
 var  scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("test1")).scope();
            var _html='<div>{{name}}-</div><mydirectivewithtemplateonly  waytoload="Generated Dynamically Using Template" >Not Succeed</mydirectivewithtemplateonly>';
           $('#content').html($compile(_html)(scope));
           setTimeout(function(){ scope.$apply();});
```

here is the custom directive I am using TemplateUrl

```
app.directive('mydirectivewithtemplateurl',function ()
    {

      return {
     scope : {
       loadedstate:'@waytoload',

     },
    //template:'<div>{{loadedstate}}</div>',
     templateUrl:'grid.html',

    }
    })
```

and here is the custom directive that I am using Template :

```
app.directive('mydirectivewithtemplateonly',function ()
{

  return {
  scope : {
   loadedstate:'@waytoload',

 },
template:'<div class="panel panel-primary">{{loadedstate}}</div>'
// templateUrl:'grid.html',

} })
```

So my question is : how to solve evaluating angular expression  correctly inside the custom Directive when I use **TemplateUrl**  (instead of Template ) and  load it **dynamically** (jquery and @compile)   for better understanding about my problem please see  the full demo with the code  : http://plnkr.co/edit/f2eUdUwQF7o4pMCOHkLw?p=preview
and feel free to update directly the code .
**Please Note :** defined Path in TemplateUrl is correct and is tested when added directly to that page 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something todo with async loading that template, timing could be an issue, so use a promise, try putting the call to the template in a link function and comment out templateURL :

```
link : function(){
   $templateRequest("grid.html").then(function(html){
      var template = angular.element(html);
      element.append(template);
      $compile(template)(scope);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Jason, you are right , I just also needed to add  scope.$apply(); after compilation

Answer (score 0):

You could try an absolute path:

```
...
templateUrl: 'app/directives/mydirective.html'
...
```

Comment: The path is already defined correctly , I have no issue with the path as you see the file "grid.html" it is directly in the root , and this custom directive is loaded correctly when I put directly to the page my issue is  when loaded dynamically the full code is in the link shown on my question